# Twitter login without TwitterLoginButton

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

Is there any built-in way to initiate a login without using the `TwitterLoginButton`. All examples that I could find use a `TwitterLoginButton`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works.

```
TwitterAuthClient mTwitterAuthClient= new TwitterAuthClient();
mTwitterAuthClient.authorize(activity, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {

    @Override
    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
        // Success
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    mTwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
}
```

Comment: not work getting toast 'unable to complete the action

Comment: @Nirmit This answer is so old. The SDK has changed so much since then.

Comment: then any solution for that